# "Recent HTTP errors" not displaying in Traefik dashboard

Tags: rust, traefik

Recent HTTP Errors are not displayed on our Traefik dashboard.

I have included HTTP statistics as according to [the documentation](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/api/#metrics).

```
[https]
  [http.statistics]
  recentErrors = 10
```

This is our Traefik configuration:

```
debug = false

logLevel = "DEBUG"
defaultEntryPoints = ["https","http"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
  [entryPoints.https.tls]
  [entryPoints.traefik]
  address = ":8080"
    [entryPoints.traefik.auth]
       [entryPoints.traefik.auth.basic]
       users = []

[retry]

[https]
  [http.statistics]
  recentErrors = 10

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "enginex.nl"
watch = true
exposedByDefault = false

[acme]
email = "developer@enginex.nl"
storage = "acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
onHostRule = true
  [acme.httpChallenge]
  entryPoint = "http"


[traefikLog]
  filePath = "traefik.log"
  format   = "json"

[accessLog]
  filePath = "access.log"
  format = "json"

[api]
entryPoint = "traefik"
dashboard = true
debug = true
  [api.statistics]
  recentErrors = 10
```

I expect the dashboard to display the recent HTTP errors.